# awk filtering fails for '/\x20-\x7F/'

Tags: awk

Can someone help with this?
Why does the command

```
awk '!/\x20-x7F/
```

print the letter "a" when provided with the letter "a" running in CentOS 5, coreutils 5.97, bash 4.2.0(1) ?  This command should negate filtering the letter "a" since the letter "a" is \x61.

Also,

```
awk '/\x20-x7F/
```

does NOT print the "a" in the same circumstances, but WILL print characters greater than \x7F ?

Answer (score 2):

Character ranges are enclosed in square brackets, e.g. `[0-9]` and negated with the carret char, e.g. `[^0-9]`. Try `awk '/[^\x20-\x7F]/'`, assuming `\x20` and `\x7F` identify some characters.

Comment: Thanks, Ed.  I get a Syntax Error on the opening "[" .

Comment: @user3877935 It should be `awk '/[\x20-\x7F]/'`.

Comment: This `awk '!/\x20-x7F/` should become  `awk '/[^\x20-\x7F]/'` or `awk '!/[\x20-\x7F]/'` and this `awk '/\x20-x7F/` should become `awk '/[\x20-\x7F]/'`

Answer (score 1):

Regex does not work this way.

```
/\x20-x7F/
```

This means characters `-x7F` (`space` + `-` + `x` + `7` + `F`)

It does not go from -> to.  It just convert  `\x20` to space and use the rest as charactes.

```
cat file
1 a
2 b
3 -x7F
4 c
```

This gives line 3 since it has the pattern you are looking for.

```
awk '/\x20-x7F/'
3 -x7F
```

Her it takes all line except line 3

```
awk '!/\x20-x7F/'
1 a
2 b
4 c
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to type the backslash in front of the x7F in my stackoverflow example, although it is there in my command line.  So,  awk '/\x20-\x7F/'   does not work as I would like.

Comment: @user3877935 If you add the backslash, it will become ` - ` . where the last space is ascii 127 (7f).  It is an expression, not from one character to another.  It just the same as `/a-b/`

Comment: Thank you.  I don't quite understand your comment.  What awk statement would you write to print only lines composed of the characters in the range x20 through x7F ?

Comment: @user3877935 This just test three characters `x20` and `-` and `x7F`, not to and from.  Se Post by Ed using brackets to get range. This `awk '/[\x41-\x44]/'` will print the line if it contains one of this characters. `A,B,C or D`

Comment: Thank you.  I tried awk '/[\x20-\x7F]/' and it also prints the line for characters beyond 7F.  Do you know why?

Comment: Also, try the following data using awk '/[^\x20-\x7F]/', and it fails:
run()
MZ       ÿÿ  ¸       @

Comment: @user3877935 I have no experience with this, so cant help you more. It seems for me that you run this within some kind of script/program.  Try from bash prompt with a simple text file.

Comment: Tried, same results.  Bump?

Comment: @user3877935 Sorry but can not help you.  You do not write how you run it, where you run it, what you like to get out of it.

Comment: Thanks.  I had written "... running in CentOS 5, coreutils 5.97, bash 4.2.0(1) ..."  I am using the command line to enter the awk commands.

Comment: @user3877935 Can you post the file or some of the file you are running this on, and the expected result.

Comment: I would like to attach the file, but I don't know how to do that (am new to this site).  Can you advise?  Also, I note that when I use the command line awk '/[\x80-\xFF]/' I get the message "awk: fatal: Invalid collation character: /[�-�]/"  and I checked my $LANG is set to en_US.UTF-8"

Comment: @user3877935 Do `cat filename` then cut and past. Also use `putty` to access the terminal.

Comment: Thank you.  I paste the file after the colon:�5$���z$v��]ܬy��ԢTMmxD�&��
this is the only line with all alphabetical characters

���ܬ��Ԣܮ�
run()
MZ�